# tensorflow multi-GPUs running at same time?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, distributed-computing, multi-gpu

For the purpose to know about mechanism of distributed tensorflow, I wrote a simple test code of tensorflow using multi-gpus

```
def cv_data(SEED):
    np.random.seed(SEED)
    return np.random.rand(5,2,2)


def test(data):
    for i in range(5):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' %i ):
            with tf.name_scope('cv%d' %i):
                x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[2,2],name='x')
                y = tf.matmul(x,x)
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess = tf.Session()
    with sess as sess:
        writer=tf.summary.FileWriter("test_graph",sess.graph)
        sess.run(init)
        print("y is ")
        print(sess.run(y,feed_dict={'cv0/x:0':np.ones((2,2)),'cv1/x:0':2*np.ones((2,2)),'cv2/x:0':3*np.ones((2,2)),'cv3/x:0':4*np.ones((2,2)),'cv4/x:0':5*np.ones((2,2))))
        #tf.train.Saver.save(sess,"./model")
        writer.close()
```

But the sess.run() execute only the /gpu:4's graph, how can I let all the gpus run at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You can build up a Python list of ops and pass all of them to `sess.run`. Or you can aggregate the results (e.g. `tf.add_n`) and run that op.

Either way you probably want a single placeholder outside of the loop, meaning that you'll feed the value and it will be copied to all of the devices.

Comment: Thanks, is this what you mean ?
`sess.run(['cv2/MatMul:0','cv1/MatMul:0'],feed_dict={'cv0/x:0':np.ones((2,2)),'cv1/x:0':2*np.ones((2,2)),'cv2/x:0':3*np.ones((2,2))}) #runing at the same time`
I found it is indeed running parallel